# mailchimp subscription error message tweak jquery

Tags: jquery, css, mailchimp

hey guys so i have this mailchimp form here

```
        <div id="mc_embed_signup">
            <form action="" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
                <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
                    <div class="mc-field-group form-group">
                        <label for="mce-EMAIL">BE THE FIRST TO GET NOTIFIED WHEN THE WEB APP GOES LIVE</label>
                        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email form-control" id="mce-EMAIL">


                        <input type="submit" value="GET NOTIFIED" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button btn btn-default">

                        <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                            <div class="response success"></div>
                            <div class="response error"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
                    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true">
                        <input type="text" name="b_bc12ead653de8cf1a8d33aaf8_a777cdf5c9" tabindex="-1" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

My goal is do two things

1. when the submit button is clicked on the form display certain styles depending on the val of the input
2. if the button is clicked again remove the previous applied styles. Right now if i submit the form the messages will stack. So if i enter a proper email ill get the `success` message class and if i enter a empty value, ill get the `error` message class, but they'll stack on top of each other. Im trying to find a way i can 'refresh' the form and remove the styles so they dont stack

right now i have the following jquery code (dont worry about document.ready i have other code)

```
            $("#mc-embedded-subscribe").click(function(){
                if ($('#mce-EMAIL').val() === '') {
                    $('div.error').attr('id', 'mce-error-response');
                } else {
                    $('div.success').attr('id', 'mce-success-response');
                }
            });
```

this simply checks the value of the input and triggers on click. But thats the farthest ive gotten cause im not sure how to "refresh" the form so the styles can go away.

and here is my css styles

```
        #mce-error-response {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            width: 444px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #D23434;
            color: #FFF;
            font-weight: 500;
        }

        #mce-success-response {
            display: block;
            float: left;
            width: 444px;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #5ba5af;
            color: #FFF;
            font-weight: 500;
        }
```

Comment: toggle classes instead of switching ID's. Very simple to use `addClass()` ... `toggleClass()` and `removeClass()`. Also helpful for checking `hasClass()`. More complicated keeping track of ID just for style

Comment: @charlietfl can you show me in code

Comment: API has examples for every method and sections of API show various methods grouped. http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this JQuery code:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#mc-embedded-subscribe").click(function (e) {
            var clearValues = $('#mce-responses div').siblings().removeAttr('id');
            //e.preventDefault(); uncomment to see effect
            if ($('#mce-EMAIL').val() == '') {
                clearValues;
                $('div.error').attr('id', 'mce-error-response');
            } else {
                clearValues;
                $('div.success').attr('id', 'mce-success-response');
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Basically i'm first getting rid of the id attribute everytime there's a click event on that button. I'm using the [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method to select your two divs to have the toggle effect.

Let me know if it works!

Comment: this is a good start but other stuff surfaced that doesnt cover the scope of my original question. Thank you regardless